# Trying to set multiple property values in xml using xpath

Tags: xml, xpath

Starting off,
I am trying to adjust a mod I created for a game (7 Days To Die)
I don't really have a lot of experience with XML modification. But I got it to do what I wanted.

However I don't want to run through EVERY item in the list to have to adjust the values of items.

Example of the XML file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
<item name="ammo9mmBulletBall">
    <property name="Tags" value="ammo"/>
    <property name="DisplayType" value="ammoBullet"/>
    <property name="HoldType" value="45"/>
    <property name="Meshfile" value="#Other/Items?Misc/sackPrefab.prefab"/>
    <property name="DropMeshfile" value="#Other/Items?Misc/sack_droppedPrefab.prefab"/>
    <property name="Material" value="Mbrass"/>
    <property name="MeltTimePerUnit" value=".4"/>
    <property name="Stacknumber" value="300"/> <!-- STK ammo high -->
    <property name="EconomicValue" value="9"/>
    <property name="Group" value="Ammo/Weapons,Ammo,Ranged Weapons"/>
    <effect_group name="ammo9mmBulletBall" tiered="false">
        <passive_effect name="EntityDamage" operation="base_set" value="32" tags="perkGunslinger,9mmGun"/>
        <passive_effect name="BlockDamage" operation="base_set" value="6" tags="perkGunslinger"/>
        <passive_effect name="DamageModifier" operation="perc_add" value="-.8" tags="earth"/>
        <passive_effect name="DamageModifier" operation="perc_add" value="2" tags="wood"/>
    </effect_group>
</item>
</items>
```

Example off the mod file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configs>
<!-- * * * * * * * * * * ammunition / arrows / bolts / fuel * * * * * * * * * * -->
<set xpath="/items/item[starts-with(@name, 'ammo')]/property[@name='Stacknumber']/@value">500</set>
```

My problem is, there are other items in the XML document that start with "ammo" that I do not want to change.

I have attempted to find info on having an exception in the xpath, so something like:

```xml
<set xpath="/items/item[starts-with(@name, 'ammo'[not(@name, 'ammoBundle')])]/property[@name='Stacknumber']/@value">500</set>
```

However that obviously didn't work.
Is there a way to do this? Or am I going to have to stick to doing each value edit manually?

Another alternative I looked into, was if it was a part of the Group "Ammo/Weapons,Ammo,Ranged Weapons"
But I could not find information on that either.

If anyone could help me, that would be great.

Edit:
I was able to achieve a portion of what I am after with:

```xml
<set xpath="/items/item[starts-with(@name, 'ammo') and not(contains(@name, 'Bundle'))]/property[@name='Stacknumber']/@value">500</set>
```

However I am still trying to change a property value based on the the item(s) found using the above, by the property value already set: `<property name="Group" value="Ammo/Weapons,Ammo,Ranged Weapons"`
So if the items have the property value listed above, they will adjust their 'Stacknumber' property value.
Unsure if that is possible.

Edit: Further examples
So this is just the items themselves, no properties for each line.

```xml
Example of what I want to include
<item name="ammo9mmBulletBall">
<item name="ammo9mmBulletHP">
<item name="ammo9mmBulletAP">
<item name="ammo44MagnumBulletBall">
<item name="ammo44MagnumBulletHP">
<item name="ammo44MagnumBulletAP">
<item name="ammoDartIron">
<item name="ammoShotgunBreachingSlug">


Example of what I want to exclude
<item name="ammoJunkTurretRegular">
<item name="ammoJunkTurretShell">
<item name="ammoJunkTurretAP">
<item name="ammoBundleMaster">
<item name="ammoBundleJunkTurretRegular">
<item name="ammoBundleJunkTurretShell">
<item name="ammoGasCanBundle">
<item name="ammoArrowFlamingSchematic">
<item name="ammoCrossbowBoltExplodingSchematic">
<item name="ammoGasCanSchematic">
<item name="ammoProjectileZombieVomit">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you only want to modify the `item` whose `@name` is "ammo9mmBulletBall" then use `item[@name='ammo9mmBulletBall']` rather than `item[starts-with(@name, 'ammo')]`

Comment: No, I want to adjust multiple items within the xml document that start with "ammo" however there are others that start with ammo that I do not wish to alter,

As I said, was able to use a "and not(@name), however I can only do it once, I cannot specify multiple conditions.

Comment: You need to provide examples of the cases you want to include and the cases you want to exclude. You can combine multiple conditions, but you haven't made it clear what the conditions are. At least, I don't understand what your exact requirements are. Can you include the entire file, and add comments showing which elements you want to include and exclude?

Comment: In XPath your boolean condition are treated as "predicates" by enclosing them in square brackets, and you can combine predicates simply by putting one square-bracketed predicate after another in the XPath. e.g. `foo[@type='bar'][not(baz='quux')]`, or you can use the boolean `and` operator within a single predicate e.g. `foo[@type='bar' and not(baz='quux')]`

Comment: I will update the question, however I wont add the whole file, as it is a LONG file and not all of it is relevant.

Comment: as I mentioned in the earlier comment, if I have add a second 'and' predicate, it errors out, I will get the exact error and paste it here shortly.

I have not attempted using individual square-bracket predicates, will attempt that.

Answer (score 0):

I've made a few XML mods for 7D2D and, although you can chain 'and' statements, I'd recommend avoiding it, as it quickly grows and becomes unreadable.

Instead, find the most common starting phrases you can that won't include the ones you don't want, and use those:

```xml
<set xpath="//item[starts-with(@name, 'ammo9mm')]/property[@name='Stacknumber']/@value">500</set>
<set xpath="//item[starts-with(@name, 'ammo44Mag')]/property[@name='Stacknumber']/@value">500</set>
<set xpath="//item[starts-with(@name, 'ammo762mm')]/property[@name='Stacknumber']/@value">500</set>
...
```

(Note the double slash // at the beginning there means match the following item wherever it appears, you can drop the initial /items/ as a result.)

Trust me, I'm a software developer and I understand the desire to get one beautiful xpath to capture them all, but the time you spend trying to find it will dwarf the amount of time it actually takes to kick out the 8 or 9 separate xpaths that will do the same job. And with these configs, it is very rare that you need more than a dozen to achieve the result.

However, if you are committed to chaining 'and' statements, then I think the problems you had were likely typo related. I just tried this and it worked without issue:

```xml
<set xpath="/items/item[starts-with(@name, 'ammo') and not(contains(@name, 'Bundle')) and not(contains(@name, 'Junk'))]/property[@name='Stacknumber']/@value">500</set>
```

You can test it on [this xpath tester](https://www.freeformatter.com/xpath-tester.html), you can even upload the *items.xml* file to get an exact match for everything that will be found in game.